# Fixed Div using scrollToFixed plugin coming onto the adjacent floated div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-float

I'm using  [scrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) plugin to fix the position of a div. 
Here is the html code i'm using

```
<div id="header">
</div><!-- header -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="nav-top">
</div><!-- end nav-top -->
<div id="content">
    <div id ="nav-left">
    </div><!-- end nav-left -->
    <div id ="main-content">
    </div><!--end main-content -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end content -->
<div id ="footer">
</div>
```

and css

```
    *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul,li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
body{
    min-width:1024px;
    background-color:#F3F4F8;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
}
#nav-top{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#1F415A;
}
#content{
    width:1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    /*min-height:px;*/
    margin-top:30px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
}
#content #nav-left{
    width:172px;
    min-height:550px;
    border:1px solid #DBDFE8;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
}
#content #main-content{
    /*margin-right:184px;*/
    float:right;
    width:828px;
    min-height:550px;
    border:1px solid #DBDFE8;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#footer{
    width:1024px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top:1px solid #B7B8BD;
    height:85px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    color: #6F7072; 
}
.clear{
    clear:both; 
}
```

and jquery code goes here

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#nav-top').scrollToFixed();
        $('#nav-left').scrollToFixed({ marginTop:60,
        limit : $('#footer').offset().top - $('#nav-left').outerHeight() -19 - $('#nav-left').offset().top
        });
    });
```

**problem:** when the window width is equal or less than 1024px it works perfectly fine but when the window width is more than 1024px the `nav-left` is overlapping with `main-content` here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHtRQ/) for the same try expanding the width of the document more than 1024px you can see the difference. Help me out here please.

**Edit:** And also i need to avoid `footer` coming onto `nav-left` so i must use `limit` in `scrollToFixed` . If i remove limit overlapping of `nav-left` on to `main-content` is stopped but it will make the `footer` to overlap with `nav-left`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the scrollbars and remove the scrollFixed position accordingly. I have added the following code:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

        if ($("body").width() > $(window).width()) {

            $('#content #nav-left').trigger('remove.ScrollToFixed');
        }
    });
```

and here is the **[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GHtRQ/25/)**